# Remove row any in table use angular2

Tags: angularjs

I want update to page html when click remove row any in table. I used the code of AngularJs 2.0 follow, but not update to page html. Please help me.Thank you very much !

**Shipping.Component.html**

```
 `<div class="example table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Giá trị đơn hàng</th>
                            <th>Giá ship</th>
                            <th>Xóa</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let row of shipping.shipping_config; let i=index">
                            <td>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control fromgtdonhang gtdonhang" [(ngModel)]="row.from" placeholder="Từ">

                                <input type="number" class="form-control gtdonhang" [(ngModel)]="row.to" placeholder="Đến">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="row.shipping_fee" placeholder="Giá ship">
                            </td>
                            <td class="formatremove">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="removeKhunggia(i)"> 
                                    <i class="icon wb-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" class="formatbuttonadd">
                                <button type="button" (click)="addKhunggia()" class="btn btn-outline btn-primary">
                                    <i class="icon wb-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Thêm
                                </button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>`
```

In Shipping.component.ts:

```
 `ngOnInit() {
        this.shippingService.getShopingConfig().subscribe(res => {
            this.shipping = res;
            this.rowsShippingConfig = res.shipping_config;
        });
    } 
removeKhunggia(id: number) {
        this.rowsShippingConfig.slice(id,-1);
    }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `slice` returning new array, and the original array will not be modified. So you may want to use `splice` in `removeKhunggia` like this:

```
removeKhunggia(id: number) {
 this.rowsShippingConfig.splice(id, 1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the value after removing,

```
removeKhunggia(id: number) {
  this.rowsShippingConfig =   this.rowsShippingConfig.slice(id,1);
}
```